# Running flask app using Apache and mod_wsgi not working

Tags: windows, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get my app for production using Apache 2.4, but I get network error which I think means my flask app isn't running.

When I'm running Apache and navigate to the web, i get - network error:

### Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

First, is there a way to debut it? because nothing is in the log. maybe a way to check if the Apache even calls my .wsgi file?
And also I attached my code, and I can really use some help!

some details:
I'm using Apache 2.4 and python 3.7.4.
My app file is: Operator.py
inside "C:\users\myapp" directory

I added the reference to wsgi with:
LoadFile "C:/python37/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/users/myapp/venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/users/myapp/venv/"

### httpd.conf (in Apache):

```
Define SRVROOT "c:/Apache24"
ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"

Listen 80

LoadFile "C:/python37/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module 
"C:/users/ihen2622/documents/jgh_prototype/venv/lib/site- 
packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/users/ihen2622/documents/jgh_prototype/venv/"

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
 User daemon
 Group daemon
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin admin@example.com

<Directory />
 AllowOverride none
 Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.py
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
 Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

 <IfModule logio_module>
   # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
 </IfModule>
 CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
 AllowOverride None
 Options None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
 RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
 TypesConfig conf/mime.types
 AddType application/x-compress .Z
 AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
 AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
 Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
 SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
 SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

### httpd-ssl.conf(Apache):

```
...
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/dist"
ServerName thenameoftheserver:443
WSGIScriptAlias \ "C:/Users/myapp/web.wsgi"

<Directory "C:/Users/myapp>
Require all granted
</Directory>



</VirtualHost>
```

### web.wsgi (in my app, python):

```
import sys
import logging

activate_this = r'C:/Users/myapp/venv/Scripts/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Users/myapp")

from Operator import app as application
```

### my app (python):

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
#! C:\python37\python
import cgitb
from flask_cors import CORS

cgitb.enable()

# load app
from init_app import app

db.create_all(app=app)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "https://thecorrectpath/*"}})

@app.route('/')
def analytics():
    print('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host=HOST, debug=DEBUG, threaded=True)
```